# MATLAB ode45 doesn't start at initial conditions

Tags: matlab, ode, computational-physics, differential-equations

I wrote a code in MATLAB to solve a system of differential equations, but my solution doesn't seem to take into consideration the initial conditions I specified. I am not sure how to interpret this problem. 
In the code below, r_0 is equal to 32612336, but the output rsol starts at 0:
[image: output]
I will be extremely grateful for any ideas/help!

```
% %function definitions
syms r(T) p(T) T Y t

G= 4.30091252525*(10^(-3)); %grav constant, in (parsec*km^2)/(Ms*sec^2) 
M = 170000; %mass of the Black Hole, in solar masses
m = 30; %mass of the object, in solar masses
reduced = m*M / (m+M);
c = 0.0020053761; % AU/sec, speed of 
rs = 2*G*M / c^2; %Schwarzchild radius
PI = 3.14;
E = 89656170000.0000;
L = 2.592191000000000e-13;

ode1 = diff(r,T) == sqrt((E^2/c^2 - c^2) + 2*parsec_to_AU(G)*M/r*(1+L^2/((c^2)*(r^2)))-(L^2)/(r^2));
ode2 = diff(p,T) == (1/r^2) * L;


% %function setup
[f1, Subs]= odeToVectorField([ode1 ode2]);
F1= matlabFunction(f1, 'Vars',{T,Y})

%
r_0= 32612336; %In KM
p_0 = PI;
span = [0 10^(-11)];
conditions = [r_0;p_0]; 
options = odeset('MaxStep', 10^(-14),'AbsTol',10^(-7));
[rsol,psol] = ode45(@(T,Y)F1(T,Y),span,conditions,options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out the time steps.

If you print out the solution, you should find the IC is initialized properly.